# 2 electrons with the same spin in the same orbital

Tags: electrons, orbitals, spin

When two electrons are in the same orbital and they have the same spin do we say that the electronic configuration is impossible or that it refers to an excited state?

Comment: As your question is written: "Impossible."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle

Comment: this question can have a good explanation in physics!

Answer (score 7):

It is impossible. Having two electrons with the same spin in the same orbital is a violation of the Pauli exclusion principle.